# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "dar la brasa"?

Tags: modismos, etimología, expresiones

Se utiliza bastante en España la expresión **"dar la brasa"** cuando alguien molesta hablando profusamente sobre un tema.

Por ejemplo:

> Juan siempre está dando la brasa con el fútbol, parece que no sepa
>   hablar de otro tema.

He estado buscando pero no encuentro ningún origen conocido para esta expresión. ¿Alguien lo sabe? Además, ¿se usa también en otras regiones?

Comment: En Chile no se usa. Tal vez se refiera a largas conversaciones a la luz de la fogata. A medida que los leños se apagan, van quedando solo las brasas tibias y los amigos más dados reflexionar, probablemente un poco ebrios.

Comment: La expresión proviene de la jerga juvenil, no conozco su origen, pero sospecho que tiene que ver con la acción de compartir cigarrillos entre la juventud. Si el que está con el cigarro en la mano, en lugar de fumar está hablando sin parar, éste se consume, con lo que cuando se lo pasa al compañero lo que queda del mismo es prácticamente nada, apenas "la brasa", de ahí provendría el "dar la brasa" cuando alguien habla mucho y de seguido. Variantes de la misma expresión serían "dar la turra", "turrar" o "dar el turrón", de incierto origen también.

Answer (score 2):

Tampoco he conseguido averiguar el origen de esa expresión. Sin embargo, encontré una referencia sobre el uso de la misma en una novela escrita en 1998:

> **"... tío, ese bardeo te lo regalé yo, y un regalo no se regala,
>   protestó Mónica. Anda, amor, no des la BRASA ".**
>    (Beatriz y los cuerpos celestes, pág. 200).

Dada esta referencia y la escasa información acerca del origen de dicha expresión, se me ocurre que este coloquialismo pudiera ser relativamente reciente (incluso puede que por la misma razón no se ha incluido en el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/brasa)).

Sobre el uso de esta expresión, te aseguro que por lo menos en México no la utilizamos (quizá tampoco en nigún otro país de Latinoamérica) y estoy casi seguro que sólo se utiliza en España.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta! A ver si alguien nos sabe decir el origen. Por cierto, no entiendo el -1 que recibiste.

Comment: @fedorqui, Yo tampoco entiendo el voto negativo, en fín. Creo que una aclaración no estaría de más.

Answer (score 2):

En algunos pueblos de España, existe una fiesta llamada "los fuegos de San Juan". En la cual se enciende un gran fuego para después solo dejar las brasas, entonces los pueblerinos pasan descalzos por encima de ella, a veces llevando a alguien a hombros:

[image]

El cómo consiguen pasarlas sin sufrir heridas es un misterio, pero referiendose a la expresión creo que viene de que la gente daba mucho el coñazo para que alguien se metiera en las brasas, por ahí debe estar el origen.

Eso además explicaría porque esa expresión solo se da en España.

Answer (score 0):

Viene de la expresión "Que pesado!", aquí en España cuando algo quema, decimos también que "pesa", por ejemplo, cuando comes algo caliente y te preguntan como esta dices "pesa un poco", de ahí a que se haya buscado un objeto caliente para designar a la persona pesada. Pero antes de evolucionar al actual "dar la brasa" vino el "eres un brasas".

Comment: ¿En qué zona de España se usa la expresión "pesa un poco"? Nunca la  había oído.

Answer (score 0):

Esta palabra viene de una costumbre muy antigua que precisamente no es directamente, sino que puede entenderse indirectamente al brasero de la foto, esta costumbre tiene que ver con los cocineros, en este caso los braseros, que aparentemente no paran de hablar del mismo tema siempre, si alguien se les acerca no solo no se callan sino que machacan el mismo tema siempre, por eso la expresion dar la brasa o el coñazo, que es que choca todo lo que dice.

Answer (score 0):

Acá en Chile se usa un eufemismo criollo, "dar la cacha", el cual tiene la siguiente acepción.

"Dícese de la situación en la que un sujeto no hace nada, pierde el tiempo, o hace algo de manera ineficiente e incorrecta".

Ejem. «Diste la cacha jugando el partido».
«Estai puro dando la cacha compadre, concéntrate».

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/24715)

Answer (score 0):

Se dice dar la brasa cuando alguien se comporta de manera muy pesada.

Esta expresión viene de calentar a alguien la cabeza por hablarle tanto sobre un tema que no le interesa.

Por lo tanto podría ser una metáfora ya que las brasas calientan o queman (dependiendo de la intensidad o de lo "vivas" que estén), al igual una persona que se empecina en algo que no necesariamente ha de interesar a quién interpela.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuestas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!